# GMSCameraPosition not accurate

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, maps, gmsmapview

I am using GMS to show map locations in my iOS app using the following code. The position of the camera is not centered at marker position but it is slightly north(around 5 miles) of it. How can I center camera position to center on marker?

```
 let marker = GMSMarker()
 marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: latitude!, longitude:longitude!)

 let camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withTarget: marker.position, zoom: 10.0)
 let mapView = GMSMapView.map(withFrame: view.bounds, camera: camera)

 marker.map = mapView

 cell.mapView.addSubview(mapView)
```

[image: The initial view of the map]
Above is the initial location of the map.
[image: location of the marker]
The marker is south of the initial view.

Comment: I think, it not problem with GMSCamera position, it should problem with the frame of map view.

Comment: Thanks for your help. You were right, it is due to view.bounds. "view" is actually viewcontroller view and not mapview.

Comment: you can debug UI to make sure your map view frame is correct or not

Comment: @2ank3th Have you solved this issue? i am facing same issue

Answer (score -1):

The view in `withFrame: view.bounds` is not the correct `mapView`. Changing that to `mapView` fixed the problem.